# CSR and private key generated twice but still prone to drown attack

Tags: csr

1. we generated the CSR and private key
2. Installed SSL cert and was Graded F as our server was prone to DROWN attack. Somehow the private key was the same as another key of an existing server that has SSLV2

We generated another CSR with another private key, got the new cert and still face the same issue.

What is causing the problem?

Comment: Who is doing this grading -- SSLLabs? I don't think they compare to any other server, and only look at yours. Note if you tried to configure this using only cipher settings in OpenSSL not protocols directly there was a bug that _did_ enable SSLv2 when it shouldn't, see https://blog.qualys.com/securitylabs/2016/03/04/ssl-labs-drown-test-implementation-details and https://www.openssl.org/news/secadv/20160301.txt

Comment: we are using globalsign OrganizationSSL. The grading is done by globalsign: we key in our domain name in the url provided by global sign

Comment: I haven't used any GlobalSign test; can you point me to documentation?

Comment: https://globalsign.ssllabs.com/analyze.html

Comment: Okay, that's actually SSLLabs just with a GlobalSign logo tacked on. On rereading more carefully I see SSLLabs _does_ use Censys data to (try to) find other servers; can you add to your Q exactly what the report says in the DROWN entry?